# Not able to read column for HTML scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to scrape data table from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_electric_vehicles_in_the_United_States

I used following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

mech = Browser()
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_electric_vehicles_in_the_United_States"
page = mech.open(url)
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table",{ "class" : "wikitable" })

for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
col = row.findAll('th')
Vehicle = col[0].string
Year1 = col[2].string
Year2 = col[3].string
Year3 = col[4].string
Year4 = col[5].string
Year5 = col[6].string
Year6 = col[7].string
Year7 = col[8].string
Year8 = col[9].string
Year9 = col[10].string
Year10 = col[11].string
Year11 = col[12].string
Year12 = col[13].string
Year13 = col[14].string
Year14 = col[15].string
Year15 = col[16].string
Year16 = col[17].string
record =(Vehicle,Year1,Year2,Year3,Year4,Year5,Year6,Year7,Year8,Year9,Year10,Year11,Year12,Year13,Year14,Year15,Year16)
print "|".join(record)
```

I get this error

```
 File "scrap1.ph", line 13
    col = row.findAll('th')
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Can anybody let me know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides @traceur's point about the indentation error, here's how you can simplify the code dramatically:

```
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mech = Browser()
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_electric_vehicles_in_the_United_States"
soup = BeautifulSoup(mech.open(url))
table = soup.find("table", class_="wikitable")

for row in table('tr')[1:]:
    print "|".join(col.text.strip() for col in row.find_all('th'))
```

Note that instead of using `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` (3rd version of BeautifulSoup), you'd better use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` (4th version), since the 3rd version is no longer maintained.

Also note that you can pass `mech.open(url)` directly to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor instead of manually reading it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I still get IndentationError on your script.Please help me how to remove that.

Comment: @Auguster hm, there are no indentation problems here, check that you've pasted the code correctly.

Comment: i pasted same code and got this error.  File "scrap1.py", line 10
    print "|".join(col.text.strip() for col in row.find_all('th'))
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @Auguster indent the line that starts with `print`.

Comment: great help all i had to do is i took the print line in same line as for loop, this could be happening because i am editing in windows and using cygwin to run the code.